# Automatically "test and enable" CRM Mailbox

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have some mailboxes that get disabled at irregular times, all it needs is someone to click the "test and enable mailbox" button and it springs back into life.

We have a check in place which tells us when and which mailbox goes down, but is there a way of automatically running this process without human interaction.

Comment: I would be more interested in what is causing the mailbox to get disabled. Are there any logs being generated? Which CRM version is this occurring for? On-Premise or On-Line (I'm assuming on-premise)?